# How to read input from Stdin with fork()

Tags: c, linux, process

I want to read input from Stdin. And I use fork() method in C. I have child and parent process. My input is multiline. Parent process will simply wait for the termination of the child process.Child process will read just first line.After the child terminates, parent will continues to read. And I want print lines. For Example; input ->

1. Monday
2. Tuesday
3. Wednesday

Child process prints 'Monday', parent process prints 'Tuesday' and 'Wednesday'. Once end-of-file is
reached the program terminates.

./program < input.txt

Comment: possible duplicate [fgets() call with redirection get abnormal data stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45656781/fgets-call-with-redirection-get-abnormal-data-stream)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK; sounds straight-forward — at least, as long as you're typing the input.  In fact, it is hard to make it go wrong.  What did you try and what happened when you tried it?  Please read up on how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verfiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

However, it gets (a lot) trickier when you're reading from a file.  The problem is that when you read from the terminal, the standard I/O routines in the child get the first line of data and then let the process work with that.  The child exits without reading the second line, so the parent can pick up where the child left off. If, instead, you're reading from a file, the standard I/O routines read a buffer full of data, which can be many lines.  And what the child reads, the parent can't.  So, what works with terminal input doesn't work with file input.

How can you avoid the problem?  'Tis hard.  One possibility, which would probably be regarded as cheating, is to have the initial (parent) process read one character before forking.  This fills the buffer with one line if the input is coming from a terminal, or with the initial buffer full if reading from file.  After forking, the child process can read the first line (`fgets()`) and print it and exit.  Meanwhile, the parent process also has the first line of data in its copy of the input buffers (remember, the forked child and parent are almost identical after forking), so it can read and ignore the first line (the child is processing that), and then read and print the remaining lines.  It can then wait for the child to die in a loop, and finally read the remaining lines.  This leads to:

```
/* SO 4263-5451 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int c = getchar();
    if (c == EOF)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Standard input was empty!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    ungetc(c, stdin);
    //setvbuf(stdin, 0, _IOLBF, 0);

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to fork()!\n");
        exit(2);
    }
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        /* Child */
        char line[4096];
        if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read line in child\n");
            exit(3);
        }
        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
        printf("Child: read [%s]\n", line);
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        int corpse;
        int status;
        while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0 && corpse != pid)
            printf("Parent: child %d died with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
        char line[4096];
        if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read line in parent\n");
            exit(4);
        }
        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != 0)
        {
            line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
            printf("Parent: read [%s]\n", line);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This yielded:

```
Child: read [Monday]
Parent: read [Tuesday]
Parent: read [Wednesday]
```

I tried a variant setting line-buffering with `setvbuf(stdin, 0, _IOLBF, 0);` but that didn't affect the file input (on a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.3 with GCC 6.3.0), though it too worked fine with terminal input.

One option would be to replace the standard I/O functions with file descriptor code, and to use `read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1)` to read characters one at a time.  This is slower (lots of system calls) but reliable:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static int input_char(int fd)
{
    char c;
    if (read(fd, &c, 1) != 1)
        return EOF;
    return c;
}

static size_t input_line(int fd, char *buffer, size_t buflen)
{
    int c;
    size_t bufcnt = 0;
    while (bufcnt < buflen - 1 && (c = input_char(fd)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '\n')
            break;
        buffer[bufcnt++] = c;
    }
    buffer[bufcnt] = '\0';
    return bufcnt;
}

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid;

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to fork()!\n");
        exit(2);
    }
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        char line[4096];
        if (input_line(STDIN_FILENO, line, sizeof(line)) == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read line in child\n");
            exit(3);
        }

        printf("Child: read [%s]\n", line);
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        int corpse;
        int status;
        while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0 && corpse != pid)
            printf("Parent: child %d died with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
        char line[4096];
        while (input_line(STDIN_FILENO, line, sizeof(line)) != 0)
        {
            printf("Parent: read [%s]\n", line);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you brother.

Comment: it is even trickier with file redirection: [fgets() call with redirection get abnormal data stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45656781/fgets-call-with-redirection-get-abnormal-data-stream)