# fgets() call with redirection get abnormal data stream

Tags: c, gets, multiprocess

I was about to write a shell with C language. Here is the source code below:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
getcmd(char *buf, int nbuf)
{
  memset(buf, 0, nbuf);
  fgets(buf, nbuf, stdin);
  printf("pid: %d, ppid: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
  printf("buf: %s", buf);
  if(buf[0] == 0) {// EOF
    printf("end of getcmd\n");
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}

int
main(void)
{
  static char buf[100];
  int fd, r, ret;

  // Read and run input commands.
  while((ret = getcmd(buf, sizeof(buf))) >= 0){
    if(fork() == 0)
      exit(0);
    wait(&r);
  }
  exit(0);
}
```

When I execute the compiled executable with redirection of stdin to a file named t.sh which the content of is "1111\n2222\n" like ./myshell < t.sh, the output is:

```
pid: 2952, ppid: 2374
buf: 1111
pid: 2952, ppid: 2374
buf: 2222
pid: 2952, ppid: 2374
buf: 2222
pid: 2952, ppid: 2374
buf: end of getcmd
```

Obviously, function getcmd() get 3 lines(1111, 2222, 2222), while there are only 2 lines in t.sh. And these situation get even worse when putting more lines in t.sh.

And the main process is the only process execute getcmd, which we can tell by the output of pid.

By the way, I find if the line of code wait(&r) is removed, the output can get normal.

Comment: Very intriguing actually.  I can reproduce the behaviour on *4.10.0-19-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 6 17:04:57 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux*. When redirected from a file, it seems that the file pointer is reset each time.

Comment: That might explain the unused `int fd` in the code `:)`

Comment: I can reproduce the problem on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS; it does not reproduce on macOS Sierra 10.12.6.  It smacks of a bug in the Linux libraries, somehow, but that's pretty weird — as is the alternative option of it being a bug in the compiler on Linux.  I had to revise the code to pay attention to the return value of `fgets()` on Linux; I compile with `-Werror`, and got told `ignoring return value of ‘fgets’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result`.  (The macOS headers don't use that feature.)  I also had to deal with various other warnings (unused variables, variables set but unused, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `wait` ensures that the child process gets time to run before the parent finishes with the file. If I `strace` the file under Linux, I get

```
% strace -f ./a.out
[lots of stuff]
wait4(-1, strace: Process 29317 attached
 <unfinished ...>
[pid 29317] lseek(0, -2, SEEK_CUR)      = 0
[pid 29317] exit_group(0)               = ?
[pid 29317] +++ exited with 0 +++
<... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 29317
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=29317, si_uid=1000, si_status=0
    _utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
[lots of stuff]
```

The child process *rewinds* the standard input as one of the first operations after the `fork`, after which it will promptly exit. Specifically it rewinds back as many bytes from the stream as was read into it by `fgets` into buffer but still *unused*. *libc* does that automatically after the fork. I also saw the *child* process flushing the `stdout`.

I am not sure what to think about this... but clearly if you want to write a shell, you *mustn't* interact with the standard streams with *`<stdio.h>`* **at all**. If the `lseek` *didn't* occur, then the child process would see up to 4095 bytes of the `stdin` being skipped! You must always use just `read` and `write` from `<unistd.h>` instead. Alternatively, you might have some luck with adding the following call into the beginning of `main` before anything is read from `stdin`:

```
if (setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0) != 0) {
    perror("setvbuf:");
   exit(1);
}
```

This will set the `stdin` stream to *unbuffered mode*, so it shouldn't read too much. Nevertheless, the [Linux manual page for `fgets`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) say:

> It is not advisable to mix calls to input functions from the
>          stdio  library  with low-level calls to read(2) for the file
>          descriptor associated with the  input  stream;  the  results
>          will be undefined and very probably not what you want.

BTW, this cannot be reproduced if `stdin` comes from a pipe instead:

```
% echo -e '1\n2' | ./a.out  
pid: 498, ppid: 21285
buf: 1
pid: 498, ppid: 21285
buf: 2
pid: 498, ppid: 21285
buf: end of getcmd
```

But naturally that makes the other problem visible - that the child sees input being skipped.

---

P.S.

You never check the return value of `fgets` so you do not know when a read error occurs.

> If a **read error** occurs during the operation, **the array contents are indeterminate and a null pointer is returned.**

Comment: @afr0ck I believe it is a poor attempt at making both the parent and child see the file pointer at the position that it would have been positioned at were there no buffering. However I cannot find documentation about this *at all*.

Comment: It sounds like a bug to me.  I can think of no excuse for that seek in the child.  It is unwarranted interference.  And it doesn't reproduce on some other systems (specifically, macOS Sierra 10.12.6).  Good analysis of what happens, though.  Well done!